# Redirection to index in Django and Angular

Tags: angularjs, django, redirect, indexing

I have a project with Django and Angular.

I have a page located at http://localhost:8000/install/#/, that is part of the *install* app. There I have a button which POST a form, then I want the function in my controller to redirect to http://localhost:8000/, my index page.

```
$http.post('install/send_install_form/', installation) //installation is a dictionary
        .then(function(data){
            alert('You will be redirected')
            setTimeout(function(){
                    // REDIRECTION TO THE INDEX..?
                },
                4000
            )
        },
        function(data){
            alert("Error")
        })
```

How do we link between and out of apps with Django-Angular?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect within the angularJS app:

```
scope.$apply(function() { 
   $location.path("/route"); 
});
```

Redirect outside the angularJS app:

```
window.location.replace('http://google.ca/');
```

Comment: Oh actually, this worked well:

window.location.replace('/');

Thanks!